# Summation using Lambda C# 3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a small thing.

```
public int GetSum(List<int> x)
{
    foreach (int i in x) sum += i;

return sum;

}
```

where x is a List of integers defined as

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
            l.Add(4); l.Add(2); l.Add(5); l.Add(8); l.Add(6);
```

and has been passed as `GetSum(l)`

Is it possible to rewrite the above foreach loop using a lambda?

Reason: I started looking into the lambda stuffs since yesterday and is interested to learn .. however simple it  may be.

Thanks.

Comment: **Never** name a variable `l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ already has a [`Sum` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442.aspx):

```
list.Sum();
```

You can rewrite your `GetSum` method using C# 2.0's `List<T>.ForEach` method, like this:

```
public int GetSum(List<int> x) {
    int sum;
    x.ForEach(i => sum += i);   
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't really answer the question... obviously "Newbie" has figured out how to sum the elements in the sequence; he was asking for an example with a lambda.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I asked for 1 solution but you showed me two ways of doing the same. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

[`Aggregate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) was made for operations like this:

```
public int GetSum(List<int> x)
{
    return x.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot too. Since I cannot mark both the answer as accepted and I already promised @slack about that, so I am sorry this time. Next time definitely I will mark yours. But once again, thanks a lot.